# Get the relative path of the URL and insert in hidden fields

Tags: url, field, hidden

This is an HTML form, which I need to capture the structure of the URL to send to the backend.

I have the example URL:

```
https://mywebsite.com/en/specialized-areas/agrifood
```

I would like to separate the URL into:

- en
- specialized-areas
- agrifood

And send each of these URL snippets in a hidden field different from the form:

```
<input type="text" value="en" class="text">
<input type="text" value="specialized-areas" class="text">
<input type="text" value="agrifood" class="text">
```

So far I have this script, which takes the parts I need. but I don't know how to insert it into the form fields.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var newPathname = "";
    var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 3; i < pathArray.length; i++) {

      newPathname += pathArray[i] ;
      if (i< pathArray.length-1){
        newPathname += "/";
      }

    }
    console.log(newPathname);
```

Can you help me with this script?

Comment: Hi, what language are you using, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @on8tom. This is an HTML form, which I need to capture the structure of the URL to send to the backend.

I have included the code snippet I already own.

Comment: so it is JavaScript? You can use the DOM and create new input elements type hidden name and value, and append it to your form

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to do @on8tom

Comment: with document.createElement, you can create an DOM element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Ok. And how do I get the parts of the URL separate? @on8tom

Comment: Like the first line of your example code ?